# Django. REST Framework. Rename SerializerMethodField()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the django rest framework, I have a serializer, it takes fields from the model, combines it under one tag, and displays it in xml. Everything is simple.
I understand how it works. But what I don’t understand is how to rename the parent tag.

I will show:

```
#serializers.py

class kvSerializerLivingSpace(serializers.ModelSerializer):
unit = serializers.CharField(default='qm')
    class Meta:
        model = kv
        fields = ['unit', 'value']

class kvSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
living_space = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
    model = kv
    fields = ['living_space']

    def get_living_space(self, obj):
    return kvSerializerLivingSpace(obj).data
```

I need `living_space` through a hyphen. To make it look like `living-space`

I know that i can rename tags as follows:

```
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields.update({
            'living-space': kvSerializerLivingSpace()
        })
```

But this does not work for `serializers.SerializerMethodField()`

Thank!

Comment: Have you try `to_representation` before? That is a function of a serializer which you can use to turn the serialized data format to what ever you want. Here is the link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
self.fields.update({
    'living-space': serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_living_space')
})
```

The code you had does not work because you were using `kvSerializerLivingSpace` without a source for the data thus DRF tries to pull the data from model field that has the same name as the serializer field (`living-space`), which does not exist.

If you really want that method to just serialize the whole object, you don't need it. Instead, you can do:

```
self.fields.update({
    'living-space': kvSerializerLivingSpace(source='*')
})
```

The star means the whole object is used as a source.

For more info: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

Comment: **voll**, hello! You are absolutely right. It works! Thanks for the advice!